# How to download all attachments from one e-mail in OWA

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

How can I download (at once) all attachments included in a single e-mail I've received in OWA?

Some of the Google search results tell me to click the paperclip icon next to the sender's name but there is no paperclip icon there.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally there is a `Download all` link, as correctly illustrated by Franck Dernoncourt's answer. However I ran into the same issue as Joooeey (OP), namely that that link is missing.

In my case, I finally found the culprit: one of the attachments can't be downloaded, I can only `Preview` (left below), compared to the usual `Download` option (right):

[image: Two screenshot snippets; the left one shows a dropdown menu on an attachment with a "Preview" option, and the right one shows a dropdown menu on another attachment with a "Download" option.]

(The reason for this being really dumb, namely that the attachment is an email with the subject line ending in ".com", so I suppose it was mistaken for a suspicious file extension or something?)

**If you find any such un-downloadable individual attachment, they're the reason you can't download everything.** As a workaround, if you want to download all the rest together, **you can forward the email to yourself without them** (remove them individually in the forward compose window), and then you should get the precious `Download all` link.

Answer (score 3):

Typically there is a `Download all` option:

[image]

Comment: This may look obvious but the UX of this application is painful. Most toolbars are disguised a regular text, what makes it really hard to discover them.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález +1, I confirm the UI sucks.

Answer (score 0):

If the attachments are shared as links to files hosted on SharePoint, there is a special workaround for the missing "Download All" button:

[image: screenshot]

- Click the drop-down next to one of the individual attachments
- Click "Copy link"
- Remove the last bit of the URL and visit the link

  - e.g. https://companyX.sharepoint.com/personal/userX/Documents/Attachments/<s>filenameX.JPG</s>
- Select and download the desired files